# Why doesn't VScode display letters when using in a virtual machine on MacBook Air M1

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine, display

I installed ubuntu on my MacBook Air M1 and after that I installed VScode on the virtual machine.

But when I use the command palette or when I open files, there is no display of the text (the names or the commands are not visible). Can someone please help me with this?

Here is a screenshot:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYwYS.png)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue using an Ubuntu 20.04 VM in UTM with an M1 Macbook, I managed to get it working by disabling gpu acceleration.

Try running VS Code using the following command in the terminal:

`code --disable-gpu`

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the font that vs code uses wasn't installed with ubuntu, and vs code can't find a different font. Here is the font is should be using: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Droid+Sans+Mono Hope that helps!